# multiple column update with the value of other column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two tables

fw_invitations

```
id    moduleid   qdetailid
1       1          10  
2       2          11
3       3          12
4       7          13
5       8          14
```

fw_ind_details

```
id    moduleid   officeid
 10       0         100 
 11       0         110
 12       0         120
 13       0         130
 14       0         104
```

the column qdetaild is the primary key in `fw_ind_details`.what i want to do is  want to take the `moduleid` from `fw_invitations` table for that particular `qdetailid` and want to **update** in `fw_ind_details`.that is it should be done with an update query.

**desired output**

fw_ind_details

```
   id    moduleid   officeid
   10       1         100 
   11       2         110
   12       3         120
   13       7         130
   14       8         104
```

this is what i tried so far;

```
UPDATE `fw_ind_details` 
SET `moduleid`=(select moduleid 
               from fw_invitaions fo,fw_ind_details fi
               where f0.qdetailid=fi.id
                             )
```

i know my approach is wrong,any suggestion will be appreciated.

I am open for the use of PHP.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the reply and answer.  i have a question,there is a possibilty that one idetailid is assigned to two modules i.e. to two different moduleid ,how to handle this?thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE fw_ind_details d
JOIN fw_invitations i ON i.qdetailid = d.id
SET d.moduleid = i.moduleid
```

To get a particular module ID when there are multiple matches, you can join with a subquery; this example uses the highest module ID:

```
UPDATE fw_ind_details d
JOIN (SELECT qdetailid, MAX(moduleid) moduleid
      FROM fw_invitations
      GROUP BY qdetailid) i
ON i.qdetailid = d.id
SET d.moduleid = i.moduleid
```

Comment: Gah you beat me haha.. +1 for getting the same

Comment: @Barmer: thanks a lot :) will accept it also +1.cant expect a better answer.

Comment: @Barmer : i have a question,there is a possibilty that one idetailid is assigned to two modules i.e. to two different moduleid ,how to handle this?thanks in advance

Comment: It will assign each of them in turn, and the last one assigned will be the final result. You may be able to use `ORDER BY` to control this.

Comment: @Barmar you mean order by d.moduleid?

Comment: `d.moduleid` is all 0, so ordering by that is useless. It would be `ORDER BY i.moduleid` to get the highest module ID.

Comment: @Barmar if you dont mind can u please elaborate?

Comment: Actually, it turns out that you can't use `ORDER BY` with multi-table `UPDATE`, so you can't control which module ID will be used.

Comment: However, you can join with a subquery, I'll update the answer to show it.

Answer (score 3):

Use a join...

```
UPDATE `fw_ind_details` 
JOIN fw_invitations ON fw_ind_details.id = fw_invitations.qdetailid
SET fw_ind_details.moduleid = fw_invitations.moduleid
```

Answer (score 2):

The SQL to use is:

```
UPDATE `fw_ind_details` fi
   SET `moduleid`=(SELECT moduleid 
                     FROM fw_invitaions fo
                    WHERE fo. qdetailid =fi.id
                         )
```